# Connect to cloud server using Expo

Tags: ios, react-native, amazon-ec2, server, expo

I'm brand new to Expo and don't understand how development builds work. If I want to build an Expo app and run it on my iPhone, is it possible to connect the app to my own cloud server? Or am I restricted to using an Expo server for everything? I only get errors when I use my AWS EC2 instance that is running Node.js server on an IP address that I have proven accessible from anywhere. I can post my errors, but I just want to know whether it's possible to fix them first.